# Headache with makefile loop and function call

Tags: bash, function, for-loop, makefile

I have the following code in a Makefile:

```
NODES = celery1 celery2 celery3 priority export
get-status = /bin/bash -c "ps -p `/bin/bash -c '[ -a log/$(1).pid ] && cat log/$(1).pid || echo 1'` -o command= | grep $(1) > /dev/null && echo \"[$(1)] Appears to be running\" || eval 'echo \"[$(1)] Not running\" && exit 1'"

celery-status:
    for n in ${NODES}; do $(call get-status,$$n); done
```

I can't manage to make it work. And when I do:

```
get-status = /bin/bash -c "ps -p `/bin/bash -c '[ -a log/$(1).pid ] && cat log/$(1).pid || echo $(1)'` -o command= | grep $(1) > /dev/null && echo \"[$(1)] Appears to be running\" || eval 'echo \"[$(1)] Not running\" && exit 1'" 1 displaying the argument instead of 1

celery-status:
    for n in ${NODES}; do echo $(call get-status,$$n); done # echo the statements
```

Here is the output:

```
/bin/bash -c ps -p  -o command= | grep celery1 > /dev/null && echo "[celery1] Appears to be running" || eval 'echo "[celery1] Not running" && exit 1'
/bin/bash -c ps -p  -o command= | grep celery2 > /dev/null && echo "[celery2] Appears to be running" || eval 'echo "[celery2] Not running" && exit 1'
/bin/bash -c ps -p  -o command= | grep celery3 > /dev/null && echo "[celery3] Appears to be running" || eval 'echo "[celery3] Not running" && exit 1'
/bin/bash -c ps -p  -o command= | grep priority > /dev/null && echo "[priority] Appears to be running" || eval 'echo "[priority] Not running" && exit 1'
/bin/bash -c ps -p  -o command= | grep export > /dev/null && echo "[export] Appears to be running" || eval 'echo "[export] Not running" && exit 1'
```

It looks like the `$(1)` does not work, maybe I'm not escaping correctly.

I'm a bit desperate here :/

Comment: What happens if you escape the single quotes: `/bin/bash -c "ps -p \`/bin/bash -c \'[ -a log/$(1).pid ] && cat log/$(1).pid || echo $(1)\'\` -o command= | grep $(1) > /dev/null && echo \"[$(1)] Appears to be running\" || eval \'echo \"[$(1)] Not running\" && exit 1\'" 1 displaying the argument instead of 1\``

Comment: In fact I found the solution: `get-status = /bin/bash -c "ps -p `/bin/bash -c '[ -a $$0 ] && cat $$0 || echo 1' $(1)` -o command= | grep $(2) > /dev/null && echo \"[$(2)] Appears to be running\" || eval 'echo \"[$(2)] Not running\" && exit 1'" It appears that there was a problem in the execution of the /bin/bash: the second call now get the argument from the first one

Comment: Cool. Put it in as an answer and give yourself credit for it! :)